# Updating friendly name of a liferay page through SQL

Tags: sql, liferay, liferay-6

Is there a way to update the Liferay's site page's friendly name through a SQL script?

We generally do this in the control panel through admin user.

Answer (score 3):

While @steven35's answer might do the job, you're hitting a pet peeve of mine. On a different level, you're doing it right if you're doing it on the Control Panel, or through the API and you should not think about a way to *ever* write to Liferay's database. It *might* work for the moment, but it might also fail in unforeseen ways - sometimes *long after* your update.

There have been enough samples for this to happen. If you're changing data while Liferay is running, the cache will not be updated. In case these values are also indexed in the search index, they won't be updated there and random later uses might not find the correct page without you reindexing everything. The same value might be stored somewhere else - or translated. Numerous conditions can fail - and there's always one condition more than you expect and cater for. That one condition might break your neck.

Granted, the friendly name of a page might not fall into the most complex of these cases, but just don't get into the habit of writing to Liferay's database. Or, if you do, don't complain about future upgrades failing or requiring extra work, because the database contains values that the API didn't expect. The problem is that during the next upgrade (if you do it in - say - one year) you'll long have forgotten that you manually changed data in the database and blame Liferay for problems during your upgrade.

Changing data is *exactly* what the UI and the API are for.

Answer (score 0):

Friendly urls are stored in LayoutFriendlyURL.friendlyURL in your Liferay database so the following query should work

```
UPDATE "yourdatabase"."LayoutFriendlyURL" SET "friendlyURL"="/newurl" WHERE "layoutFriendlyURLId"=12345;
```

You will also need to update the Layout table accordingly to match the new friendly url.

Comment: Single quotes are invalid for SQL identifiers. You need to use double quotes.

Comment: I know. You can also use ` but it's a special character in the SO editor so I changed to to this

Comment: You can use that dreaded backtick in a formatted code block. But the backtick is also invalid in (standard) SQL. The table names in Liferay never require quoting anyway. So you neither need the backticks nor the double quotes. And string constants **do** need to be enclosed in single quotes in SQL. `"/newurl"` is a column reference in (standard) SQL

Comment: I copy and pasted this from mysql workbench and it quoted everything so I thought I'd leave them quoted

Comment: How do you know Veeru is using MySQL? (which doesn't care about SQL standards)

Comment: I don't. I'm assuming he knows enough sql to be able to change it according to his needs if this doesn't work.